# 2d array index out of range exception

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

As soon as i enter the while loop the program throws Index out of range exception, without getting rows and columns value. getint is a method to get user input while making sure the values are in range

```
 while(filled>0)
        {
            row = getint("row:  ");
            row--;
            column = getint("column:  ");
            column--;
            fields[row, column]=getint("value:  ");
            filled--;
        }
```

edit:

```
static int getint(string question)
    {
        string temp;
        int tempint=0;
        while (check != 0)
        {
            check = 0;
            Console.Write("\nPlease enter the {0}",question);
            temp = Console.ReadLine();
            if(!int.TryParse(temp, out tempint))
            {
                check++;
            }
            if(question.Length<14 & (tempint<1 | tempint>9))
            {
                check++;
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
            }
        }
        return tempint;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without getting rows and columns value"? We have no idea what those methods do, or what the size of `fields` is. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If the exception is thrown as soon as you enter the while loop then the problem is probably in `getint()`, but you've failed to include that code.

Comment: Alot more code required. Is this meant to read bottom to top for example?

Comment: You're using the wrong operators. You should be using `&&` and `||` instead of `&` and `|`.

Comment: Where do you instantiate `fields`?

Answer (score 0):

if the code out of bounds can only happen in  `fields[row, column]`  the You can add a check for out of bound of row and column

```
row = Math.Max(row,0);
column= Math.Max(column,0);

row = Math.Min(fields.GetUpperBound(0), row);
column= Math.Min(fields.GetUpperBound(1), column);
```

Comment: That only checks the lower bound. And it's more of a clamp than a check.

Comment: Thanks ,I have update my answer to include upper bounds checking as well

Answer (score 0):

so, the error was in while loop, i missed the fact that i used global variable "check" and did not reset its value of so when it exit the loop first time its value was set to 0 and hence the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I've added this check at the beginning of the loop which solved my issue:

```
if (arrLocations[0, 0] == null) break;
```